# How to get edges as list from graphviz file

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz

I have below .gv file which renders graph as expected but I am also trying to get how many related edges (different tree paths) are in the file

```
digraph G {
    300 -> 100 [label="3"]
    400 -> 100 [label="4"]
    500 -> 400 [label="5"]
}
```

Edit:
Added more tree nodes

```
digraph G {
    300 -> 100 [label="3"]
    400 -> 100 [label="4"]
    500 -> 400 [label="5"]
    600 -> 500 [label="6"]    
    700 -> 100 [label="1"]
    800 -> 700 [label="2"]
    900 -> 800 [label="3"]    
    1000 -> 100 [label="1"]
    2000 -> 1000 [label="2"]
    3000 -> 2000 [label="3"]
    4000 -> 2000 [label="4"]
    5000 -> 4000 [label="5"]
    5000 -> 3000 [label="6"]
}
```

Expecting below lists to be created from above tree

```
[300 , 100]
[600 , 500 , 400 , 100]
[900 , 800 , 700 , 100]
[5000 , 4000 , 3000 , 2000 , 1000 , 100]
```

Is there a way graphviz can provide this info or any other python module that can help with this?

Comment: What result (count) would you expect if a graph had only one (terminal) head and only one (terminal) tail, but it had many branches in the middle (i.e. all the branches merged)?

Comment: I would not have that scenario but if there are multiple middle branches then merge all of them into a single list. since all of the middle branches lead to one head, in this case a branch has started on it's own (300 -> 100), so I am trying to find such scenarios.

Comment: Would you attach a larger, more realistic example.  I think I have your answer, but need a larger graph for testing.

Comment: I have added more tree nodes that's realistic, please share any solution you may have.

Comment: Please add the complete list of paths you expect from your example, so people can easier see what you mean.

Comment: updated expected output lists from tree

Answer (score 1):

This is not done using Python, but it only uses Graphviz progs & a shell script.  Also the output will need to be reformatted, but I assume you can do that.

1. a one-liner **gvpr** program (**gvpr** is a Graphviz program) to list every node with **indegree==0** (no input edges).
2. for each such node use the **cliptree** **gvpr** program that comes (usually) with the Graphviz package (look in **/usr/share/graphviz/gvpr**)

Here:

```
gvpr 'N[indegree==0]{print ($.name)}' subTree1.gv  | while read N; do gvpr -a $N -f $DIR/cliptree  subTree1.gv;done
```

The output:

```
digraph gvpr_result {
        300;
        100;
}
digraph gvpr_result {
        100;
        400;
        500;
        600;
}
digraph gvpr_result {
        100;
        700;
        800;
        900;
}
digraph gvpr_result {
        100;
        1000;
        2000;
        3000;
        4000;
        5000;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to run this command from python code using subprocess and see an error, while is not recognized as an internal or external command. Does this command work on both Linux and Windows?

Comment: I am able to test this on Linux OS but it did not work on Windows. I could not find cliptree when I downloaded graphviz for windows.